# How to get more insight into why documents fail to be ingested in Watson Discovery Service

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

I'm using the `DiscoveryV1` module of the `watson_developer_cloud` python library to ingest 700+ documents into a WDS collection. Each time I attempt a bulk-ingestion many of the documents fail to be ingested, it is nondeterministic, usually around 100 documents fail.

Each time I call `discovery.add_document(env_id, cold_id, file_info=file_info)` I find that the response contains a WDS `document_id`. After I've made this call for all documents in my corpus I use the corresponding `document_id`s to call `discovery.get_document(env_id, col_id, doc_id)` and check the document's status. Around 100 of these calls will return the status `Document failed to be ingested and indexed`. There is no pattern among the files that fail, they range in size and of both msword (doc) and pdf file types.

My code to ingest a document was written based on the [WDS Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/?python#add-doc), it looks something like this:

```
with open(f_path) as file_data:
    if f_path.endswith('.doc') or f_path.endswith('.docx'):
        re = discovery.add_document(env_id, col_id, file_info=file_data, mime_type='application/msword')                      
    else:                                                                                        
        re = discovery.add_document(env_id, col_id, file_info=file_data)
```

Because my corpus is relatively large, ~3gb in size, I recieve `Service is busy processing...` responses from `discovery.add_document(env_id, cold_id, file_info=file_info)` calls in which case I call `sleep(5)` and try again.

I've exhausted the WDS documentation without any luck. How can I get more insight into the reason that these files are failing to be ingested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/discovery-v1#!/Queries/queryNotices API to see errors/warnings that happen during ingestion along with details that might give more information on why the ingestion failed.

Unfortunately, at the time of this posting it does not look like the python SDK has a method to wrap this API yet, so you can use the [Watson Discovery Tooling](https://discovery-tooling.mybluemix.net) or use curl to query the API directly (replacing the values in {} with your collection-specific values)

```
curl -u "{username}:{password}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/notices?version=2017-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

The `python-sdk` now supports querying notices.

```
from watson_developer_cloud import DiscoveryV1

discovery = DiscoveryV1(
 version='2017-10-16',
 ## url is optional, and defaults to the URL below. Use the correct URL for your region.
 url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api',
 iam_api_key='your_api_key')
discovery.federated_query_notices('env_id', ['collection_id']])
```